# pre width too wide if inside display table

Tags: css

Situation: To get the layout I want I need to use table and table row.

Problem: If my pre tag is inside a table the width goes crazy and goes as wide as the text inside ignoring overflow and breaking the width

If you look at the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tx3bwpn9/) you'll see the first pre fits in the page just fine and uses scrollbars. The second one does not. I'd like the second one to act like the first but can't figure it out

HTML:

```
<div class="dummy1">
    <div class="dummy2">
        <div class="z"> <pre>the red fox jumped over the lazy dog the red fox jumped over the lazy dog the red fox jumped over the lazy dog the red fox jumped over the lazy dog the red fox jumped over the lazy dog the red fox jumped over the lazy dog</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dummyA">
    <div class="dummyB">
        <div class="z"> <pre>the red fox jumped over the lazy dog the red fox jumped over the lazy dog the red fox jumped over the lazy dog the red fox jumped over the lazy dog the red fox jumped over the lazy dog the red fox jumped over the lazy dog</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.z {
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:grey;
    display: block;
}
.z pre {
    background-color: red;
    /*overflow: scrollbar;*/
    overflow: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: why do u need table and table-row you can display it without them also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
.dummyA {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

to fix this.

> http://jsfiddle.net/tx3bwpn9/2/

A table is per default only as wide as its content, and table-cells do not respect `width` declarations as long as `table-layout` has the default value `auto`. That's why you need to assign `table-layout: fixed;`.

Comment: ugh hours lost because of a style i never heard of :(. Any idea where i can read up on tags and what they do? I was sticking html in divs and doing other workarounds that USUALLY work and it wouldn't. Hell I need a good css reference and not the long winded w3 doc

Comment: @acidzombie24 its a good CSS reference URL.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference

Comment: For css stuff, http://www.sitepoint.com/html-css/css/ is a very recommendable address. In this case, it's just that you expected `display: table;` to behave just like `display: block;`, which it doesn't. A table is per default only as wide as its content, and table-cells do not respect `width` declarations as long as `table-layout` has the default value `auto`. That's why you give it `table-layout: fixed;`.

Comment: This might be more tricky but using your fiddle I put enough text/newlines to mess up the height. I thought this solution would fix it bc it fixed width. The parent (`z`) has the height of 100px yet the pre ignores it.

Comment: Fix that by adding `.z pre { white-space: nowrap; }`.

Comment: Technically that does work by putting everything on one line. I meant something like stop it from going past the height/grey. (Demo: basically your link with a lot of text http://jsfiddle.net/tx3bwpn9/3/ VS your link where you can see the height/grey http://jsfiddle.net/tx3bwpn9/2)

Comment: Well, try `overflow-y: hidden;` to achieve that, but I'm not sure if that works on such a special element like `<pre>`.

Answer (score 1):

> The default property for table-layout is **auto** so use  **width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;** in **.dummyA class** it will solve your issue

**See explanation** : https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/

Comment: This is exactly what I have answered 90 secs before you.

Comment: actually i didn't see bro i am typing answer

Comment: No problem, even though I'm not your "bro" :)

Comment: Btw, your are using a quote for your answer. As far as I found out only the first half of the sentence actually can be found on the link you posted. This feels a bit like you're using quote just to promote visibility of your answer. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Hi please update your first lines in css like this:

```
.dummyA {

}
.dummyB {

}
```

Comment: Acidzombie24 said he needs display `table` and `table-row`, so this makes no sense at all.